# My Mackbook Pro is forcing me to use Remote Management

Tags: macbook-pro, install, recovery

I recently bought a used MBP Mid-2015 from a local shop with Mojave already installed. I wanted a clean system so I booted to recovery and erased the internal drive and started a reinstall of the os. I got an error triangle/exclam symbol and a code telling me it could not find and OS to recover from. After some googling I reset both the NVRM and PRAM. This time I was able to do a network recovery and finally got El Capitain installed. I upgraded to Mojave then Catalina, loaded a bunch of testing/diagnostics tools and checked out the laptop. The last test was to do another recovery and reset everything to factory. This is where it gets weird.

TLDR:
After erasing the internal drive and doing a os reinstall from the recovery screen I got this after the post install reboot.

[image]

Clicking Continue

[image]

Clicking Learn more about remote management

[image]

First, what is this, some kind of remote management left over from previous enterprise owner PWC?

Second, after wiping the internal disk and reinstalling os and resetting NVRAM and PRAM, how is this still here?

And third, how to I get passed this, I can't move forward.

Comment: You contact Price Waterhouse & ask them to remove it…  They're a multi-national finance company. if they made a mistake they will quickly rectify it [or just as quickly inform you that you are in possession of stolen property.] Either way, you'll get a quick resolution ;)

Comment: That was my first thought until I saw the phone number.

Comment: Phone number is odd, Address is correct & easily confirmable. They're one of the largest financial organisations in the world. International web site is pwc.com

Comment: Yeah, I just tracked them down and have a call into them.

Comment: I'd love to hear how this ended… ;)

Comment: I ended up getting in contact with the head of security for PWC in that region and he got a hold of IT, checked the serial number, found out that it wasn’t stolen but they had forgot to release it from remote management.  I still don’t understand how the remote management software could still persist after I wiped the disk and reinstalled the OS.

Comment: Excellent news. Glad they released it for you. The reason a nuke & pave wouldn't clear it is exactly why it works as a security measure. It's deep in the firmware, below the OS. Macs are truly becoming unstealable… or if stolen, an expensive, shiny brick. they're catching up to what iPhones have been for quite some time, now. I'm truly glad you got a happy end to this. :)

Comment: Didn’t know you could enable any sort of remote management in firmware. It does make it unstealable because I could not get past that screen. Thanks

Comment: Most welcome. Glad you got a good outcome on this :)